# Get Logged In FB User's albums

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

I get an empty array when I request logged in facebook user's photo albums. Following is the code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                      initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/albums"]
                                      parameters:nil
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Results: %@",result);
        }];
```

NSLog results:

```
Results: {
data =     (
);
```

While logging in, I have set the permissions as `@"basic_info",@"user_photos",@"friends_photos"`

Here is code to log in:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info",@"user_photos",@"friends_photos"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        [appDelegate getFacebookUserInfo];
        NSLog(@"Granted Perm: %@ Declined Perm: %@",[result grantedPermissions],[result declinedPermissions]);
    }];
```

The NSLog prints:

```
    Granted Perm: {(
    email,
    "contact_email",
    "public_profile"
)} Declined Perm: {(
)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When Logging in `@"friends_photos"` is not needed.
2. `@"user_photos"` permission will do the job

As per Facebook's official documentation:
**If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it.**

That is the reason, `@"me/albums"` returned empty array. Meanwhile, your app goes for review to Facebook, you can get a user's album. But the user must be one of users in your Facebook App Dashboard's Roles section.

Comment: you really saved lots of time.